# SQLAlchemy: How to use ForeignKeyConstraint to parent table in polymorphic inheritance?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model, where `Edge` is an Association Object connecting `Node`s, and is being subclassed in order to create different types of `Edge`s. My ultimate goal is to create all fields of the subclasses dynamically in the `Edge` class itself (or later with a mixin).
`Edge` has a composite primary key consisting of the two foreign keys to the `Node` table, and a `edge_type` field, that also acts as the discriminator for the subclasses.
For this to work I need to connect the subclasses with a `ForeignKeyConstraint` to the composite primary key of the `Edge` class. Now, to create this `ForeignKeyConstraint` dynamically I am defining it with `@declared_attr`, but cannot reference the `edge_type` column that should be inherited from the `Edge` table to the subclasses, but I am getting the following exceptions:

```
File "/data/foo/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 194, in __getitem__
return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'edge_type'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

<snip>

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't create ForeignKeyConstraint on table 'hierarchy': no column named 'edge_type' is present.
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Edge(HasTablename, Base):

    from_node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Node.id), primary_key=True)
    to_node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Node.id), primary_key=True)
    from_node = relationship(Node, foreign_keys=from_node_id,
                             backref=backref('from_edges')
    to_node = relationship(Node, foreign_keys=to_node_id,
                           backref=backref('to_edges')

    edge_type = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            return {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__.lower()}
        else:
            return {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__.lower(),
                    'polymorphic_on': cls.edge_type}

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            return (ForeignKeyConstraint(
                       ['from_node_id', 'to_node_id', 'edge_type'],
                       [cls.__base__().__table__.c.from_node_id,
                        cls.__base__().__table__.c.to_node_id,
                        cls.__base__().__table__.c.edge_type]), )


class Hierarchy(Edge):

    from_node_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    to_node_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class History(Edge):

    from_node_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    to_node_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

This works fine if I explicitly define `edge_type = Column(String, primary_key=True)` in the subclasses, but I don't know why it is not inherited, or cannot be accessed from the ForeignKeyConstraint in `@declared_attr`?

Comment: *"a composite primary key consisting of the two foreign keys to the Node table, and a edge_type field"* sounds like a terrible idea. Why don't you have a *normal* primary key and a unique constraint on those? Then the class inherited from `Edge` would have a simple reference to that primary key.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are totally right, I should really just use a UniqueConstraint!